# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ha')

Tags: reactjs, pivot-table, webdatarocks

I have try to create a webdatarocks basic table using React. But i have continuously encountered the following issues. Why this following error occurs. How to overcome this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z48Eu.png)

Comment: That error is caused by attempting to do something like `undefined.prop`. Show your full code?

Comment: import * as WebDataRocksReact from "react-webdatarocks";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WebDataRocksReact.Pivot toolbar={true} componentFolder="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/" width="100%" report="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/reports/report.json" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short guide on how to embed WebDataRocks in your React project:

1. If you don’t have a React application yet, create one by running this command in the console:
   `npx create-react-app my-app`
   `cd my-app`
2. Get the WebDataRocks React module from npm:
   `npm install react-webdatarocks`
3. Add WebDataRocks’ styles to the `src/index.js` file:
   `import 'webdatarocks/webdatarocks.css'`
4. Import the WebDataRocksReact module to the src/App.js file:
   `import * as WebDataRocksReact from 'react-webdatarocks';`
5. Open src/App.js and add WebDataRocks there using the WebDataRocksReact.Pivot component:

```
function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <WebDataRocksReact.Pivot 
         toolbar={true}
         componentFolder="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/"
         width="100%"
         report="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/reports/report.json"
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

6. Run your application:
   `npm start`
7. Open `http://localhost:3000/` in the browser — WebDataRocks is embedded into your React project.

Comment: On Removing React strict mode, Now it is working fine. Thanks for your Response.